# illegal start of expression with methods

Tags: java, logic

I'm a beginner with using becker.robots and i was trying new things like creating diferent methods for actions to make the code itself easier. However i keep receiving the same illegal start of expression error and its frustrating me. I've gotten like 5=6 errors on line 11 alone. Help someone? :(

```
import becker.robots.*;

public class excercisefour {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

   City tor = new City(7,7);
   Robot jesus = new Robot(tor, 0, 1, Direction.EAST);
   makeWalls(tor);


 private static void makeThings(City city){
    Thing t1 = new Thing(c, 1, 1);
    Thing t2 = new Thing(c, 1, 3);
    Thing t3 = new Thing(c, 3, 3);
    Thing t4 = new Thing(c, 4, 4);
    Thing t5 = new Thing(c, 3, 1);
    Thing t6 = new Thing(c, 4, 3);
 }

   private static void turnRight(Robot robot) { 
 for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 
 robot.turnLeft(); 
 } 
   }

 private static void moveToWall(Robot robot) { 
 while (robot.frontIsClear()) { 
 robot.move(); 
 } 
   }

 private static void moveSpaces(Robot robot, int n){
    while (n>0){
      robot.move();
      n--;
    }
 }



 }
```

Comment: Post the complete error message. Most likely, you have a punctuation typo somewhere. Using an IDE (I prefer Eclipse) will help you catch and fix these problems instantly.

Comment: Thank you guys for the help! Sometimes the syntax errors can be the most frustrating if you're still adjusting to java.

Answer (score 1):

Add a closing brace to the `main` method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
} <--- this
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't close out your `main` method before starting `makeThings`. Add a closing `}`.